# How to use a stored variable and random number with selenium ide

Tags: javascript, variables, selenium, random, selenium-ide

How would a stored variable (stored text) and random number work with Selenium IDE? Trying to do this combination has proved unfruitful.

Example:

```
<td>type<td>
<td>css=input.some-text</td>
<td>javascript{'storedVars.variable'
    +Number(Math.random(storedVars.rand)*100).toPrecision(2));}</td>
```

All that is output is storedVars.variable due to the field limit.

Looking for it to return the actual variable value and the random number, i.e., text53.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out.

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>variable</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=lst-ib</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars.comb=storedVars.variable+Number(Math.random(storedVars.rand)*100).toPrecision(2);}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: ... uhh, so what I did above?

Comment: actually no, try it out it won't work. you have to have the full code above to make it work. the key seeming to be setting a new stored variable within the javascript to make it work. thank you though for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You were just off a bit on your usage of storedvars:

```
<td>javascript{'storedVars.variable'
    +Number(Math.random(storedVars.rand)*100).toPrecision(2));}</td>
```

Should instead be:

```
storedVars['variable'] + Numbermber(Math.random(storedVars.rand)*100).toPrecision(2)
```

More on Randome numbers:

Math.random() returns a decimal number between 0 & 1. so to get a number between 20 & 50 you would do:

```
Math.random() * (integer range) + (starting number)

Math.random() * 30 + 20
```

So you would end up with IDE code like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Math.random() * 30 + 20</td>
    <td>rand_num</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${rand_num}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

And then you could use the varible like:

```
<td>type<td>
<td>css=input.some-text</td>
<td>${rand_num}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying; however, that is only for the random number part of the question. The full question is asking how to get text AND random number together in one line where the text is a stored variable.

Comment: Ok, Editing my answer.

Comment: Thanks for responding again. Much appreciated. Unfortunately, still not getting it to work. I've done the following:

storedVars['variable'] + Number(Math.random(storedVars.rand)*100).toPrecision(2)

storedVars[variable] + Numbermber(Math.random(storedVars.rand)*100).toPrecision(2)

javascript{storedVars['variable'] + Numbermber(Math.random(storedVars.rand)*100).toPrecision(2);}

javascript{storedVars[variable] + Numbermber(Math.random(storedVars.rand)*100).toPrecision(2);}

None of which work.

Doing the . and the [] is really just a difference in syntax, and which you prefer.

Comment: And with out the concatenation does this work? With just the number(Math.random...) bit? Are you sure you don't have a javascript error in there? Try that bit of javascript in the firebug console.